# Azure Roles Recycle - Infinite Busy State

Tags: c#, azure, azure-worker-roles

This issue started happening on Tuesday, January 24, 2017. Prior to this date, I never had problems with worker roles recycling.

Around 9 pm EST, my worker roles go into busy state. The CPU hits 90%. It stays this way for over 10 hours. It starts with one role, then it spreads to others. My software works fine during the day. My worker roles use the standard A0 extra small size. I tried increasing the size to small Standard A1, but the error persists.

My code says StorageConnectionString. I ran a debugger and I saw this error only once:

An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)

This caused an exception and the role stopped. I never saw it again, though.

I have to deploy my site to the staging server, stop the production server, and click swap to make it work. It breaks again at 9 pm later that day.

When my role is busy, here is the error that I receive:

Busy (Stabilizing role... [01/28T13:28Z]Role will recycle. Last OnRoleRun returned gracefully. Last exit time:

I did remote desktop into the event log. Here is the error that I receive:

WaWorkerHost
Failed to load role assembly: XX.TaskRole, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

[image]

Here is my code for the worker role:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue;
using Microsoft.Azure;

namespace XX.TaskRole
{
    public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
    {
        string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XX"].ConnectionString;
        CloudQueue queue;

        public WorkerRole()
        {
            ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 12;
            

        }

        public override void Run()
        {
            // This is a sample worker implementation. Replace with your logic.
            while (true)
            {
                GetTasks();
                Thread.Sleep(30000);
                Trace.TraceInformation("Working", "Information");
            }
        }

        public override bool OnStart()
        {
            try
            {
                CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
                CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

                // Create the queue client.
                CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();

                // Retrieve a reference to a queue.
                queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("taskqueue");
                return base.OnStart();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Exception Handling & Logging
                // Return false for OnStart
                
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void GetTasks()
        {
            if (queue == null)
                return;

            try
            {
                //Pull 10 - 15 rows from database. Just numbers and letters. No XML.
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe the exception occurs only once because the value fetched is cached and reused.

Comment: The error happens because assemblies are missing. Open your worker role project in Visual Studio. Right click the assemblies. If the assemblies are from NuGet, reference the ones in your solution and not on your C drive.

Answer (score 0):

> this issue started happening on Tuesday, January 24, 2017. Prior to this date, I never had problems with worker roles recycling.
>
> Around 9 pm EST, my worker roles go into busy state. The CPU hits 90%. It stays this way for over 10 hours. It starts with one role, then it spreads to others

It seems that not reaching the ready state after the OS upgrades. More info that we can refer to the [document](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kwill/2012/09/19/role-instance-restarts-due-to-os-upgrades/).

> Busy (Stabilizing role... [01/28T13:28Z]Role will recycle. Last OnRoleRun returned gracefully. Last exit time:
>
> WaWorkerHost Failed to load role assembly: XX.TaskRole, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

According to your mentioned error info, it indicates missing runtime dependencies. The following is the snipped from the  [Common issues that cause roles to recycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-troubleshoot-common-issues-which-cause-roles-recycle).

> • If using Visual studio, make sure the Copy Local property is set to True for each referenced assembly in your project that is not part of the Azure SDK or the .NET Framework.
>
> • Make sure the web.config file does not reference any unused assemblies in the compilation element.
>
> • The Build Action of every .cshtml file is set to Content. This ensures that the files will appear correctly in the package and enables other referenced files to appear in the package.

I also find another [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cie/2015/09/06/cloud-services-roles-recycling-with-the-error-system-io-fileloadexception-could-not-load-file-or-assembly/) about "Cloud Services roles recycling with the error" `System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly`. More detail info please refer to it.

Comment: Hi, I see no log entries saying System.File.LoadException. I don't think I am missing assemblies. Why would the software work for almost a day, if files were missing? As for Guest OS upgrade, I see no code indicating a long load time. Is there anything else I can try? How can I tell what files are missing?

Comment: Please have a try to redeploy it if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

There was an assembly reference error with Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime. The correct reference was \packages\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.SDK.2.9.0\lib\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll. Instead, I referenced the one on my C: drive. I used NuGet to add the assembles to my project and it worked.